# Disable "id" from get Parameter for 404 handling

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have problem with latest TYPO3 9.5.13 and get parameter "id". I have payment provider which is redirecting to successpage like /success?id=1234-id-from-paymentprovider. In TYPO3 9.5.11 it was no problem, but sind last update to 9.5.13 I get 404 page. So TYPO3 is now checking get parameter ID and sending 404 page not found.

How can I disable this?

Thanks!
Martin

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having it rewritten by the webserver (e.g. .htaccess if you use Apache).

Another possibility in v9 would be to use a middleware early in the stack. I would go for `before: typo3/cms-frontend/page-resolver` (see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jonas eberle! I solved it with .htaccess:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^success?$ /$0?vid=%1 [R=301,L,NC]